# Pytorch MLPerf training on large number of CPUs

Tags: pytorch, benchmarking, cpu-usage

I have been trying to run a training job on an instance with 192 vcpus and 1024GB of memory. Specifically, I am working with the MLPerf Image Segmentation Benchmark. I have made some edits to the reference implementation code [Here](https://github.com/mlcommons/training/tree/master/image_segmentation/pytorch), including changing the run command in run_and_time.sh like so:

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=16 main.py --data_dir ${DATASET_DIR} ...
```

Now what I really want to do is characterize the performance of training while utilizing close to all of the available vcpus. As it is, I can increase nproc_per_node to 42. But going any higher and I start to get errors popping up like so:

```
RuntimeError: [/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1607370172916/work/third_party/gloo/gloo/transport/tcp/pair.cc:575] Connection closed by peer [10.0.2.100]:57054
```

With the number of errors increasing with the nproc_per_node value. So Im presuming that there's some kind of bottleneck in IPC bandwidth that is preventing the spawned processes beyond 42 from working properly. I am quite sure I'm missing a fundamental issue that is likely keeping me from fully utilizing the CPUs.

I understand that this is not an ideal scenario for training. This is more an exercise in my own curiosity and learning. Is this likely to be an underlying issue of the limitations of the instance I've set up, or is there something I'm missing in the code that could be causing these errors?